# method execute failure block ios

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I have been using `AFHTTPClient` class' `postPath:parameters:success:failure:` method. but it always call failure block only. I have been using `AFNetworking` 0.10 library. Can anyone tell me the possible reasons for this.

following is the code:

```
NSURL *nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:kURLAuthLogin];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:nsUrl];
[httpClient postPath:nil parameters:loginParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n login success \n\n\n\n\n\n");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n login failed \n\n\n\n\n\n");

}];
```

There is no any problem with nsUrl or any other variable for sure.

Comment: any more details? this seems a bit brief

Comment: post your code u have tried for it.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that your login failed. 
It would be common sense to

```
NSLog (@"%@", error);
```

to get the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

did you made your NSString to support NSURL with adding percentage.

example:-

```
 NSString *loginCredential=[@"Your Url with login and password" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```